# Is it correct to use "make" this way?

Tags: causatives, predicative-complement

I saw a sentence on instagram: "make yourself protagonist". Shouldn't it be "make yourself be a protagonist"?

Comment: "Make oneself something" is idiomatic.  "Make smbd be" is unusual, even if correct grammatically.  A missing article before "protagonist" can be either "headlinese" or the use of the noun "protagonist" as an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Without context, it's difficult to know for sure.

I suspect it should be "make yourself a protagonist" or perhaps "make yourself into a protagonist". An alternative would be "Be a protagonist".